# Tag box 100% height of Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with custom styles. I have two tag boxes one with less text than the other.  I want the tag boxes to be the same height. I tried height: 100% and display: block; but it didn't work.

[image]

The code:

```
<div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 ">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="tag-box tag-box-v6 box-shadow shadow-effect-2"> 
                        <div class="headline">
                        <h4>Hello world1:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="tag-box tag-box-v6 box-shadow shadow-effect-2">
                <div class="headline">
                    <h4>Hello world2:</h4>
                </div>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--2nd col-->
    </div><!--offset wrapper col-->
</div>
```

Tag box code:

```
.tag-box  {
padding: 20px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tag-box-v6 {
background: #fafafa;
border: solid 1px #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this demo: http://bootply.com/129611

You can use CSS3 flexbox for this. Just add the `equal` class to the tag-box container...

```
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for accepting late. This works like a charm. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can set `min-height` for the tag-box, e.g:

```
.tag-box  {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-height:400px;
}
```